# How to sort an IList<> which is in another IList<> with a lambda expression or linq

Tags: vb.net, linq, lambda

Good afternoon.

I need to make a question.

I need to order a property type "IList" which is in a list of objects that property has.

As a matter of example, I'll explain the following:

I have the class "Tels" which has two properties: "Phone As String" and "RegDate As Date".

On the other hand, I have a class "Person" which has two properties, "Name As String" and "Tel As Ilist(Of Tels)".

The method I have loads a IList type variable and I need that the contact's phone numbers are organized on the "RegDate" property, this in a descending way

Here I attach the example code

[image]

Thank's for help.

Comment: LIN**Q** is natural for **query**, not for data modification such as sorting property items. Your `For Each` approach is good enough

Comment: Thanks har07, for now I'll keep the previously implemented it solves.

Regards.